# How can I ensure decimal precision in mongodb geospatial coordinates?

Tags: mongodb, double, geospatial, precision

I need to save longitude/latitude coordinates in mongodb and I'm not sure how to store them.  No examples I see online show conversion to string or splitting up the decimal parts into 2 ints.  I'm assuming that in order to enable geo indexing, I'd have to store them as doubles, so for example:

```
{ _id : 100, pos: { long : 126.9, lat : 35.2 }, type : "restaurant"}
```

I need at least 6 decimal places of precision, so how does this work in mongodb?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MongoDB [supports `double`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-bson-types) datatype. It is used for all floating point numbers. As MongoDB implements BSON spec, we may think of it's double as of BSON double. Which is `8 bytes (64-bit IEEE 754 floating point)` according to the [specification](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification). And [it supports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format%3a_binary64) 15-17 significant digits.

So do not worry.

Answer (score 5):

MongoDB's geospatial index uses a conventional [geohash](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/geospatial-indexes/#geospatial-indexes-geohash).  You can [configure the precision of the hash to be up to 32bits](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/geospatial-indexes/#location-precision), which gives you the equivalent of about 8 or 9 decimal places of precision.  So you'll lose some precision from doubles, but still plenty for your application.